# Prove something is less or equal to other thing using induction in COQ

Tags: coq, induction, inequality

I need to prove that the height of a formula's tree is always less than the number of nodes of the same tree, but I got stuck after the assumption and don't know how to proceed. Can somebody help me fill the "admit." spaces?

```
Require Import String.
Require Import Init.Nat.
Require Import PeanoNat.
Require Import Plus.
Require Import Le.

Theorem le_plus_trans2 : forall n m p, (n <= m) -> (n <= p + m).

Proof.
 intros n m p.
 intros x.
 apply le_trans with (m:= m).
 assumption.
 admit.
Qed.
```

Comment: Please remove "using induction" in the title of the question, so that it can be useful to other people.

Answer (score 3):

If you `Require Import Coq.omega.Omega`, you can replace all of your `admit`s with `omega`.

Alternatively, if you want a less hammer-ful solution, you can replace your `admit`s with

```
 etransitivity; [ eassumption | apply le_plus_l || apply le_plus_r ].
```

That is, you can use the fact that `x <= x + y` and that `y <= x + y`, for `x : nat` and `y : nat`.

*Edit* (after your update of the question).  Your question now contains a completely different goal, but this goal can still be solved by the standard arithmetic hammer.  If you `Require Import Coq.omega.Omega`, your entire theorem is proven by `intros; omega.`

Comment: I found a way using le_plus_trans, using the fact that as k1 <= x, k1 <= x + y. But know I need k2 <= x + y, knowing that k2 <= y. For that I created the le_plus_trans2 theorem, but still need to prove the last part xD

Comment: It's poor form to replace your question with a different one after the question has already been answered.  However, I've updated my answer with the standard solution to all problems of this form: `omega`.

Comment: Also, did you read my original answer?  The goal you have remaining is exactly the theorem statement `le_plus_r`, which I mention in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for changing it, it's just that my main goal is to complete the whole proof. I read it, but I misread the "definition" of le_plus_r, so that's why I'm confused. Anyway, thank you very much for your help and time!

Comment: No worries.  I think the general etiquette on StackOverflow is to post separate questions if a complete answer to the question you posted leaves you with new questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Plus.le_plus_trans` and `PeanoNat.Nat.add_comm`.

Comment: I did it with "le_plus_trans", but now I need something else xD